# Best Layout Manager for creating two columns in a single panel?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to create a GUI for a program with an undefined number of rows but stay with two columns. Currently the only way I can get it to look how I want is using FlowLayout but the window of course needs to be smaller than desired. It needs to happen within one panel as well because it is being added to a tabbed pane.

What would be the best layout manager to solve the problem that is in the JDK? Or would just kind of brute forcing it with AbsoluteLayout be the best approach (as the user shouldn't really be resizing the window)?

I have attached the desired appearance.

[image: sample layout]

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Seems like a 2 column JTable would be a better fit than a JPanel.

Comment: `Or would just kind of brute forcing it with AbsoluteLayout be the best approach` - that is the worst approach.

Answer (score 3):

Several layouts can do what you want. I'd suggest `GridLayout` (easy to use, but columns will be equal width) or `GridBagLayout` (harder to use, but you have lots of control). You could also use a `BorderLayout` and put all the fields in a sub-panel on the WEST and all the drop-downs in a sub-panel on the EAST. The difficulty with that is ensuring that the rows have the same height, since they won't be constrained by the layout itself.

The best thing to do would be to go through the [Java tutorial on layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and get up to speed on what the various layout managers can do.

Also, since you're using Swing, you could just use a `JTable` (as Gilbert Le Blanc suggests in his comment).